# Vagrant & Chef - Postgresql not starting on reboot

Tags: postgresql, chef-infra, vagrant, upstart, init.d

I decided to create my own chef script to install Postgres. The installation works perfectly fine, but postgres doesn't start on boot when I `vagrant reload`

Here's my recipes/default.rb:

```
include_recipe "apt"

apt_repository 'apt.postgresql.org' do
  uri 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt'
  distribution node["lsb"]["codename"] + '-pgdg'
  components ['main', node["postgres"]["version"]]
  key 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ACCC4CF8.asc'
  action :add
end

package 'postgresql-' + node["postgres"]["version"] do
    action  :install
end

file "/etc/postgresql/#{node['postgres']['version']}/main/postgresql.conf" do
    action  :delete
end

link "/etc/postgresql/#{node['postgres']['version']}/main/postgresql.conf" do
    to      node["postgres"]["conf_path"]
    action  :create
    notifies :reload, "service[postgresql]", :delayed
end

service "postgresql" do
    action [:enable, :start]
    supports :status=>true, :restart=>true, :start => true, :stop => true, :reload=>true
end
```

And here's my attributes/default.rb:

```
default["postgres"]["version"] = "9.3"
default["postgres"]["conf_path"] = "/home/vagrant/postgres/postgresql.conf"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

### **============ EDIT 1 ============**

Here is the output when running `vagrant up` for the first time with `chef.log_level = :debug`: http://pastebin.com/w8Lp8gzv

Here is /etc/init.d/postgresql: http://pastebin.com/dQ5Zb1yj

Here is /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.3-main.log: http://pastebin.com/0Y2RhWvL

### **============ EDIT 2 ============**

I'm now fairly confident that it's my postgresql.conf file, which looks like: http://pastebin.com/rjX89iU0

shared_buffers might be too high...

Comment: Please specify operating system. If at all possible, point to the basebox's URL. Adding `chef.log_level = :debug` to the `Vagrantfile` might give more clues to the problem.

Comment: Also, after reloading the Vagrant VM, can you start postgresql manually via `service postgresql start`?

Comment: I'm using `config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box"`

Comment: I can start Postgres manually by running `service postgresql start`

Comment: Weird. I recreated your scenario using the code and box you provided. Postgres starts just fine after installation, but after a reload if I issue `service postgresql start` it throws this error: `* No PostgreSQL clusters exist; see "man pg_createcluster"` and does not start.

Comment: Hrm, perhaps that has something to do with the init.d...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the postgresql was starting before the postgersql.conf file was mounted

Answer (score 0):

When you run `vagrant reload`, is the Chef Client running? I suspect not. Mitchell changed the behavior in a recent version of vagrant to only provision if the machine hasn't already been provisioned. This information is stored in the `.vagrant` directory in your working directory. In short, since you already provisioned your machine with `vagrant up`, it is *not* provisioned when you run `vagrant reload`.

1. You run `vagrant  up` - this is actually going to run `vagrant up --provision`, which executes the [Chef Client provisioner](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/chef_client.html) on the node, executing your Chef Recipe.
2. You run `vagrant reload` - this actually runs `vagrant up --no-provision`, because the `.vagrant.` directory indicates the machine has already been provisioned. So your machine is rebooted, but the Chef Client provisioner is not executed.

#### Solution

Run `vagrant reload` with the `--provision` flag

```
vagrant reload --provision
```

#### Notes

This still doesn't explain why upstart (or whatever you're using to ensure the postgres service is running at boot) isn't starting the server for your automatically. In order to answer that question, I'll need to see more information. Can you set the `chef.log_level = :debug` in your `Vagrantfile` and update your question with the output? It would also be helpful to see the `init.d` script this postgres installer creates, and any log output from `/var/log` related to postgres.

Comment: @user1161657 I think the problem is with your init.d file, which I'm not an expert on. For some reason, the postgres service is not starting on boot, and that's outside of the scope of the Chef recipe you posted.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to debug further?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, it looks like Postgresql doesn't play nice with postgresql.conf being a symbolic link.  Copying the file instead did the trick.

Comment: May I suggest you use the [official postgresql cookbook](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/postgresql)? It's very well written and should cover for your use case just fine.

Comment: My usecase needs to use a predefined `postgresql.conf`, otherwise I would :/

Answer (score 0):

If you're starting services with Upstart that depend on something in Vagrant's shared folders, have your upstart conf file listen for the `vagrant-mounted` event.

```
# /etc/init/start-postgresql.conf
start on vagrant-mounted

script
  # commands to start postgresql...
end script
```

The `vagrant-mounted` event is emitted after Vagrant is done setting up shared folders, this way you can restart dependent services after `vagrant reload` without having to run your provisioners again.